# InitState() not finishing before Build method is called

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having a problem in my home_screen.dart file. I
have a method called pullUserData() that is called in initState() but before pullUserData() is completely finished, the build method in home_screen.dart begins. This results in null values (auth and friendsList) being sent to NavDrawer() and FriendsFeed() in the build method of home_screen.dart.

How can I prevent NavDrawer() and FriendsFeed() from being called in the build method before initState() is completely finished? Should I use FutureBuilder?

User_data.dart handles gets the values for auth and friendsList.

home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:mood/components/friends_feed.dart';
import 'package:mood/components/nav_drawer.dart';
import 'package:mood/services/user_data.dart';

class LandingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'landing_screen';

  @override
  _LandingScreenState createState() => _LandingScreenState();
}

class _LandingScreenState extends State<LandingScreen> {
  FirebaseAuth auth;
  List<dynamic> friendsList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pullUserData();
  }

  Future<void> pullUserData() async {
    UserData userData = UserData();
    await userData.getUserData();
    auth = userData.auth;
    friendsList = userData.friendsList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Mood'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: NavDrawer(auth),
      body: FriendsFeed(friendsList),
    );
  }
}
```

user_data.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserData {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User _currentUser;
  String _currentUserUID;
  List<dynamic> _friendsList;

  FirebaseAuth get auth => _auth;
  User get currentUser => _currentUser;
  String get currentUserUID => _currentUserUID;
  List<dynamic> get friendsList => _friendsList;

  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    getCurrentUser();
    getCurrentUserUID();
    await getFriendsList();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() {
    _currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  }

  void getCurrentUserUID() {
    _currentUserUID = _auth.currentUser.uid;
  }

  Future<void> getFriendsList() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(_currentUserUID)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      _friendsList = value.data()["friends"];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: a futurebuilder or a splash screen where you wait for everything to load would be the best solution i think

Comment: initState will not wait for Future. All you need is a FutureBuilder. https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your code but it will work.

**Firstly**, if you want to set value of your friendslist during build, you have to use **setState** like this:

```
setState(() {
  friendsList = userData.friendsList;
});
```

And if you want to wait until *pullUserData()* finish, you are looking for something called **splash screen**, but in your problem, you are waiting only for body to be build so I will recommend to use **progress indicator** in your scaffold like this:

```
return Scaffold(
   appBar: Bars.menuAppBar('Devices'),
   drawer: DrawerMenu(),
   backgroundColor: ColorThemes.backgroundColor,
   body: _loading
       ? Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(
           valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
               Colors.blue), //choose your own color
         ))
       : FriendsFeed(friendsList)
);
```

You can see that I used **_loading** variable. You will have to define it before your *initState()* like

```
bool _loading = true;
```

Then after you set your **friendsList** inside of your *pullUserData()* function, change **_loading** to false inside of **setState** just like this:

```
setState(() {
  friendsList = userData.friendsList;
  _loading = false;
});
```